# Convert hyperlinks to plain text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, is it possible to convert a hyperlink to plain text (so that it no longer links to any page?)

For example, would it be possible to change the following link (inside the `<a>` tag) to plain text using JavaScript (so that this text no longer links to any page)?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.wikipedia.org/" target="blank" id = "wikiLink">Go to Wikipedia</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to remove its `href` attribute:

```
document.getElementById('wikiLink').removeAttribute("href");
```

If you want to completely remove the node, leaving the text, try this:

```
var toRemove = document.getElementById('wikiLink'), parent = toRemove.parentNode,
    text = toRemove.firstChild;
parent.insertBefore(text,toRemove);
parent.removeChild(toRemove);
parent.normalize();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById("wikiLink").removeAttribute('href')
```

or with jquery

```
$("#wikiLink").removeAttr('href');
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code should render hyper link as text.

$(element).find('a').contents().unwrap();

[JS BIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/leligule/2/edit)

Comment: effective and simple

Comment: This is great because the user can see there is no link at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the "link" behavior of *all* links, you can do:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) links[i].href = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery a simple way is to remove the link and to put a text node instead:

```
var $link = $('#wikiLink');
$link.after($link.text());
$link.remove();
```